# .NET possible URL regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Trying to create a regex that gets everything after the final "/" in a possible URL, providing the final character isn't a "/".

I have this so far:

```
(?<url>(http(s)?://)?([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+[.com]+?[a-zA-Z0-9\.\/\?\:@\-_=#]+(/[/?%&=]*))
```

My test URLs are

```
https://linkedin.com/in/username

https://www.facebook.com/username

username

https://plus.google.com/u/0/username/
```

This passes on all except the final one. The correct result would be `username` for each test.

Comment: what is output for third and last one?

Comment: Why use regular expression and not just `Substring` based on  `lastIndexOf`

Comment: `if (url.Contains("/") && !url.EndsWith("/")) { result = url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf('/') + 1); }` - and so on, just add the necessary logic for those strings that do not contain `/`

Comment: Also `System.Uri` has some useful features you may use.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti is right, use System.Uri for url manipulation and validation.  Much easier and more reliable.

Comment: Looked at System.Uri but it may not be a URL - depends on user input. Hadn't even considered a substring. Will give that a whirl! Appreciate the speedy feedback all :-)

Comment: Also as a note, as I realise I didn't specific, the output for ALL test should be: "username" (obviously no quote marks).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want can benefit of the Uri object the framework provides. 
It does not provide the whole solution (segments ending with "/"), but it does most of the job.

```
    List<string> strings = new List<string>
    {
        "https://linkedin.com/in/username",
        "https://www.facebook.com/username",
        "username",
        "https://plus.google.com/u/0/username/"
    };

    List<Tuple<int, string>> results = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < strings.Count; i++)
    {
        var s = strings.ElementAt(i);
        try
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(s);
            var lastSegment = uri.Segments.LastOrDefault();
            if (!lastSegment.EndsWith("/") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastSegment))
                results.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(i, lastSegment));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //s is not a valid uri and thus a valid uri object could not be created out of it
            results.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(i, ex.Message));
        }
    }

    foreach (var segment in results)
        Console.WriteLine(segment);
```

---

Output: (tuples where the number is the element index in your sample)
(the last element is not added because you do not want segments ending with /)

[image]

Comment: Well, the guys were already talking about using System.Uri above... I came too late.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to go with regex ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/nM1tN9/1)):

```
\/(\w+)$|(\w+)$|\/(\w+)\/$
```

---

If you want to go full C# and a bit of Linq:

```
List<string> urls = new List<string>
{
    @"https://linkedin.com/in/username",
    @"https://www.facebook.com/username",
    @"username",
    @"https://plus.google.com/u/0/username/",
};

foreach (string url in urls)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine(url.TrimEnd({'/'}).Split('/').Last());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<url>(http(s)?://)?([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+[.com]+?[a-zA-Z0-9\.\/\?\:@\-_=#]+(/*[/?%&=]*))
```

should cover all except "username"? 
the regex Thomas wrote should cover this?